# can someone please help me understand the code from the "function (x)" , also what is the role of $out?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm learning lapply, can someone please help me understand the code from the  "function (x)", also what is the role of "$out"? Thank you

```
outs=lapply(names(qdata[,12:35]), function(x)
        hist(qdata[[x]], data=qdata, main="Histogram of Quality Trait",
             xlab=as.character(x), las=1.5)$out)
```

Comment: Some info on `(l)apply` can be found here: [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply produces a series of histograms. If we replace `qdata` with `mtcars` and make a couple of minor tweaks we get:

```r
par(mfrow = c(3, 4))

lapply(names(mtcars),
       function(x) hist(mtcars[[x]],
                        main = "Histogram of Quality Trait",
                        xlab = as.character(x), las = 1.5))
```

[image]

What `lapply` is doing here is iterating through the column names and generating a histogram for each column.

There are a couple of oddities in the code you shared. `$out` is not a member of the object produced by `hist`, so as well as drawing the histograms, the code returns a list of `NULL` values. The `$out` is presumably just a way of preventing the list from spitting out pages of the contents of `hist` objects to the console. The `outs` variable is useless after this call.

Also, `data` is not a named parameter in `hist` so the original code produces warnings for me.

Another possibility is that this is a custom `hist` function rather than the base R version.

Comment: are we setting names(mtcars) as x in the code?

Comment: @Shabaz not quite. The function takes one string at a time, so in the function we are setting x as `names(mtcars)[1]` in the first iteration, then `names(mtcars)[2]` and so on. It's really a way of passing the `names(mtcars)` vector one at a time rather than all together.